How to plot data points with asymmetric errors, in different colors and with caps
I have written a little python script that read my data from a file, put them in several lists, and use plt.errorbars to plot the points on the lists that I needed.
this is the first part of the script where I create the lists:
name,E_cut,err1n,err1p,refl,err2n,err2p,gamma,err3n,err3p=[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
list1=[]
f=open("Parametri_Nustar.txt")

for line in f:
    
    list1.extend(line.split())
maxim=len(list1)
for i in range(0,maxim,10):
    if i==0: 
        continue
    name.append(list1[i])
    E_cut.append(float(list1[i+1]))
    err1n.append(float(list1[i+2]))
    err1p.append(float(list1[i+3]))
    refl.append(float(list1[i+4]))
    err2n.append(float(list1[i+5]))
    err2p.append(float(list1[i+6]))
    gamma.append(float(list1[i+7]))
    err3n.append(float(list1[i+8]))
    err3p.append(float(list1[i+9]))
   

this is the script for the plot:
lenght=len(E_cut)
ax=plt.axes()
y=[]
y_error=[]
error_E=[err1n,err1p]
error_refl=[err2n,err2p]
error_gamma=[err3n,err3p]

#generate 24 colors random

number_of_colors = 24
colors = ["#"+''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])
             for i in range(number_of_colors)]
#Plot data
plt.scatter(E_cut, refl,c=colors,alpha=1)
plt.errorbar(E_cut,refl,error_refl,error_E,'none',ecolor=colors,alpha=1) 


lines = [Line2D(E_cut,refl, color=c, linewidth=3, linestyle='-') for c in colors]

#put the legend on the right
ax = plt.subplot(111)
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 1.5, box.height*1.5])
ax.legend(lines,name,loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

#axis labels
plt.ylabel('refl')
plt.xlabel('E_cut')

with this I obtain different color points, with errorbar, but without caps, and if I try to insert it in errorbar, with capsize=5, capthick=2, it gives me the following error:
['#E50CCC', '#AF8DBE', '#1C258A', '#E9B80F', '#6EA256', '#8D38D2', '#93D051', '#551F32', '#C7B550', '#BF53BD', '#55EE45', '#2A4795', '#793D62', '#0C1E56', '#94B3E1', '#563F57', '#11702F', '#6CB62C', '#391820', '#9B8D7D', '#5901DC', '#EF698E', '#B694B5', '#54322B'] is not a valid value for color
How can I do in order to reach my goal?
